# Accessing An Array from within a function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I searched the forum but didn't see a similar question or answer for the question I am about to ask, however if it is duplicated please provide a link and I will view the answer in that post.

Is it possible to access objects in a array from within a closure/ function? I am attempting to do so for the purpose of experimentation.

Here is the code I put together in firebug. I am receive 'undefined'.

```
var checkers = [1, "string", null];

var i, txt = "";

function myFunction(checkers){
    for(var i = 0; i < checkers.length; i++ ){
        txt += checkers[i] + " ";
        console.log(txt)
    }
}

myFunction(checkers);
```

Comment: Where are you calling `myFunction()`? The `checkers` inside that function isn't a closure variable because it's in the parameter list.

Comment: You asked the function to take an argument named `checkers` so, in that function, `checkers` is whatever argument you provided to the function. Since you did not show your call to the function and, by extension, the arguments you provided to it, this question is 100% unanswerable. That's why the site prompted you when you joined to learn how to present [minimal, complete, verifiable testcases](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It continues to baffle me as to why I must inform almost every single question author about this obvious and basic fact.

Comment: Where are you calling the function? What argument do you pass? You don't access the array `checkers` by closure, only `txt`.

Comment: You have declared `checkers` twice, once as a global variable, once as the parameter to `myFunction`. You also have not shown how you call the function.

Comment: Your example outputs `1`, `1 string`, `1 string null`.

Comment: You say you "receive" `undefined`. What do you mean by "receive"? I presume you mean you see that on the console. That's only because the console is outputting that as the result of the function declaration. It has nothing to do with the function's behavior or result, which as others have pointed out, you would have to actually call in order to get it to anything. After you did add the call to your code fragment in your recent edit, you will see the results. So what's the problem/question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely possible, one of JavaScript's strenghts.

Your issue is that you aren't calling your function. Also you don't need a parameter to myFunction since it closes over the context and knows about checkers.

Just delete the paramter and after your code add `myFunction()` to call it.

```
var checkers = [1, "string", null];

var i, txt = "";

function myFunction(){
    for(var i = 0; i < checkers.length; i++ ){
        txt += checkers[i] + " ";
        console.log(txt)
    }
}

myFunction();
```

The reason you are getting undefined is because theres not value returned to the console when declaring a function, just like you'd get undefined if you ran:

```
var t = 'asd'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkers = [1, "string", null];

var i, txt = "";

function myFunction(checkers){
    for(var i = 0; i < checkers.length; i++ ){
        txt += checkers[i] + " ";
        console.log(txt)
    }
}

myFunction(checkers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran it and I get:

```
1
1 string
1 string null 
undefined
```

Since the function doesn't return anything, Firebug displays `undefined` at the end.